# How do you open and read large files with python?

Tags: python

The basic task is to write a function, get_words_from_file(filename), that returns a list of lower case words that are within the region of interest. They share with you a regular expression: "[a-z]+[-'][a-z]+|[a-z]+[']?|[a-z]+", that finds all words that meet this definition. My code works well on some of the tests but fails on a larger file so I think I'm opening the file wrong for bigger files.
Have no problem with these tests;

```
filename = "abc.txt"
words2 = get_words_from_file(filename)
print(filename, "loaded ok.")
print("{} valid words found.".format(len(words2)))
print("Valid word list:")
print("\n".join(words2))

#or

filename = "synthetic.txt"
words = get_words_from_file(filename)
print(filename, "loaded ok.")
print("{} valid words found.".format(len(words)))
print("Valid word list:")
for word in words:
    print(word)

#my code:
import re

def get_words_from_file(filename):
    """Returns a list of lower case words that are with the region of interest, every 
    word in the text file, but, not any of the punctuation."""    

    with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        flag = False
        words = []
        for line in file:
            if(str(line).strip()=="*** START OF"):
                flag=True
            elif(str(line).strip()=="*** END "):
                flag=False
                break       
            elif(flag):
                new_line = line.lower()
                words_on_line = re.findall("[a-z]+[-'][a-z]+|[a-z]+[']?|[a-z]+", 
                                           new_line)
                words.extend(words_on_line)
        return words
```

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: How does it fail on larger files?

Comment: If you replace `flag=True` with `continue`, then you don't need the `flag` variable at all.

Comment: Are you sure the regex is correct? It doesn't make sense, as the third part can never match.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think it's the size at all. The string "*** START OF SYNTHETIC TEST CASE ***" is wrong for that file and when I shorten it to the general string "*** START OF" none of the test code works...

Comment: My mitake, "***START OF"

Comment: What's the definition of this mysterious "region of interest"?

Comment: Section defined:

The string "*** START OF" indicates the beginning of the region of interest
The string "*** END" indicates the end of the region of interest for that file

The professor wants every word in the text file, but, does not want any of the punctuation.
They share with you a regular expression: "[a-z]+[-'][a-z]+|[a-z]+[']?|[a-z]+", that finds all words that meet this definition.

example:

import re
line = "james' words included hypen-words!"
words_on_line = re.findall("[a-z]+[-'][a-z]+|[a-z]+[']?|[a-z]+", line)
print(words_on_line)

Books that were encoded in UTF-8

Comment: in my opinion, use `yield` to return a number of lines at a time instead of keeping all lines/words in memory.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Where would yield go?

Comment: I think the problem is how I identify the start of the region of interest

Comment: you can replace last 2 lines of `get_words_from_file` with `yield words_on_line`. then use `for word in get_words_from_file(filename)`

Comment: @Tarique Making it a generator would be wrong (it wouldn't return a list).